# Error: The server does not support SSL connections

Tags: postgresql, ssl, openssl, psql

M1 Mac Monterey12.1

Error: The server does not support SSL connections

I used a postgres server to
I ran the following code.

```
DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL NODE_ENV=production yarn develop
```

[image]
I'm using strapi with a postgres server.
I did a breww install openssl.

Comment: I don't see anything that would generate an error message worded like that.  Is that a verbatim copy?

Comment: no, I uploaded image

Comment: OK.  It looks like node pg rewrites the error message the server sends it.  If you want to use SSL, then you need to configure the server to use it (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html).  If you want to not use ssl, then you need to configure the client to not use it. (we can't see where it being configured to use it, you haven't shown us that.  Maybe it is in the URL, maybe it is elsewhere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PostgreSQL server does not support SSL connections. As per [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/#connection-parameters), you should add `sslmode=disable` to your JDBC connection URL or as connection parameter.