# After moving docker-compose.yml file, I get "The server does not support SSL connections"

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, docker-compose

This is most likely due to my lack of knowledge around Docker, so I probably just need a theoretical answer but I can post some code if needed.

So, I have a containerized project that connects to a managed database on Digital Ocean through a public network connection and SSL is required so I have that configured. When I run it locally with:

```
docker compose build
docker compose up
```

everything looks fine and I can see that it connects to the DB. Then I push the new images to docker hub with:

```
docker compose push
```

and reference those images in my docker-compose.yml:

```
image: <myDockerID>/<imagename>
```

I've checked Docker hub to confirm that the images are being updated when pushing and also deleted them to make sure they were the right images being uploaded.

In my root directory I have the key files:

- docker-compose.yml
- Dockerfile
- ca-certificate.crt
- .env
- ..

From what I've read, everything looks good.
From my understanding, I should now be able to copy/paste the docker-compose file in any directory on any machine and run `docker compose up` (this might be where I misunderstand). However, when I try this, I get an SSL error.
For example, in a new directory containing only the docker-compose.yml, I would clear out old stuff then run fresh:

```
docker compose down -v --rmi all --remove-orphans
docker compose up
```

and it fetches new images and everything looks pretty good except that now I get:

```
[TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...
worker    | Error: The server does not support SSL connections
worker    |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:77:37)
worker    |     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
worker    |     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
worker    |     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
worker    |     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
worker    |     at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
worker    |     at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

So, my question is why doesn't this error present itself in the project directory? Is this error referring to the DB not supporting SSL connection (it does)? Does docker require more than just the docker-compose.yml file to run correctly?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.16.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn --production
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  app-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  server_data: {}
  worker_data: {}
  postgres_data: {}

services:
  ######################################################################################
  server:
    container_name: server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: <dockhubID>/backend2-server
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    command: ["yarn", "start:server"]
    volumes:
      - server_data:/usr/src/app
    networks:
      - app-net
    environment:
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      DB_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      DB_CA_CERT_PATH: ${DB_CA_CERT_PATH}
  worker:
    container_name: worker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: <dockerhubID>/backend2-worker
    command: ["yarn", "start:worker"]
    volumes:
      - worker_data:/usr/src/app
    expose:
      - 4000
    networks:
      - app-net
    environment:
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      DB_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      DB_CA_CERT_PATH: ${DB_CA_CERT_PATH}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I've seen the following questions but wasn't able to answer the questions that pertain to my situation:

- [Error: The server does not support SSL connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70857834/error-the-server-does-not-support-ssl-connections)
- [How to fix "Error: The server does not support SSL connections" when trying to access database in localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54302088/how-to-fix-error-the-server-does-not-support-ssl-connections-when-trying-to-a)

UPDATE: After adding the missing environment variable to the docker-compose.yml file, I'm seeing an error that makes me think I didn't set the variable correctly:

```
node:internal/fs/utils:347
worker  |     throw err;
worker  |     ^
worker  | 
worker  | Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
worker  |     at Object.openSync (node:fs:601:3)
worker  |     at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
worker  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/dist/vendure-config.js:62:30)
worker  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
worker  |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
worker  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
worker  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
worker  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
worker  |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
worker  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/dist/index-worker.js:4:26) {
worker  |   errno: -2,
worker  |   syscall: 'open',
worker  |   code: 'ENOENT'
worker  | }
```

I also see this warning now:

```
WARN[0000] The "DB_CA_CERT_PATH" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

The variable is set in `.env` as:
`DB_CA_CERT_PATH=/usr/src/app/ca-certificate.crt`

Since the Dockerfile's workspace is set to `/usr/src/app`, I assume the path should be correct. I also assume that `.env` is copied over when `COPY . .` is ran, but I could be mistaken. Just to reiterate, I'm focusing on the case where I copy the docker-compose.yml file into an empty directory. Running the container in the original directory still works fine.
Thanks again for the help!

Comment: are you sure, you are putting the yml file in your project directory when running docker compose up?
See, the thing is in docker file, you'd see copy command which copies project directories/files to the container when you do build and up. If you want to copy and run a single file anywhere/anymachine, what you want is docker image and not yml file.

Comment: @binariedMe hi, the error only occurs when I place the docker-compose.yml file in a new empty directory. I use the 'image' property in the compose file to link to the images that were pushed to dockerhub

Comment: I assume `ca-certificate.crt` is used for the SSL connection? How are you integrating this file into your app and the docker image?

Comment: Can you also copy the docker-compose file in your question? I am assuming that's where you are referencing your certificate and the path might be broken.

Comment: @Rob To use the certificate, I have a config file where I specify the configurations of my DB connection. I have a field where I specify 
`ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false, ca: fs.readFileSync(process.env.DB_CA_CERT_PATH).toString() }`
But I don't suspect this is causing the issue but I am able to establish connection when in my "development" directory (where I run `docker compose build`)

Comment: But how is this ca-certificate.crt getting into the container? Currently, you only stated that it is in the root directory next to your docker-compose.yml. Where are you setting this `DB_CA_CERT_PATH` environment variable? I cannot see any reference to this variable in either the Dockerfile or the docker-compose.yml. Is it defined in an `.env.` file? If so, is this env file also copied to the container?

Comment: @Dylan As Rob is pointing out and as per your previous comment -- the CA PATH is specified through an env var and the fact that it's working in your development is a mere coincidence. You need to specify that env var in your compose as well and make sure that the container can reach that path to grab it.

Comment: @Rob Ahh I see what you mean now. I've updated the docker-compose.yml shown above to include the DB_CA_CERT_PATH which is defined my .env file as "/usr/src/app/ca-certificate.crt". Now I receive a warning `The "DB_CA_CERT_PATH" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.` then I also receive an error after running `docker compose up`: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory` which seems to come from the fs.readFileSync() function that I posted above. From my Dockerfile, I would expect `COPY . .` to include my .env file since it's in the root as well

Comment: @AlexD. Thank you, I've made the suggested updates that Rob and yourself suggested which led to some new errors. I've updated the original post with some more information. I also removed the postgres service from the docker-compose.yml as it's my understanding that I don't need that anymore and I also added the missing variable. Thanks for taking time to help me better understand Docker

Comment: Oh it seems like I just needed to copy over the .env file along with the docker-compose.yml into a new directory. Which I guess could make sense since the .env is intended to hold sensitive information so I suppose I wouldn't want that to be part of the self-contained image. It seems to be working now how I expect. I will try to launch it on a Digital Ocean Droplet. Thanks for the input! If you want to formalize it into an answer, I will accept. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to summarize the comments by Alex D. and me:

- The assumption was that `ca-certificate.crt` is used for the SSL connection, and that your `docker-compose.yml` is where you are referencing this certificate and the path in that file might be broken.
- You stated that you are referencing the certificate file via `process.env.DB_CA_CERT_PATH`. However, it was unclear how you are setting this variable in the container, since it was not present in the `docker-compose.yml` or `Dockerfile`.
- It turns out the environment variable was not configured at all. You then added a reference to this variable in the `docker-compose.yml` file, which in turn references a "local" environment variable defined in an `.env` file, which needs to be present alongside the `docker-compose.yml`.

As you pointed out, the way you are currently defining your environment variables in the `docker-compose.yml` (e.g. `DB_CA_CERT_PATH: ${DB_CA_CERT_PATH}`), you actually are only passing your "local" environment variables on the host to that file, which are then passed into the docker container. For this reason, you also need the `.env` file alongside the `docker-compose.yml` file.

If you only want to use "a single `docker-compose.yml`" file without the local `.env` file, you can just defined the environment variables directly in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
server:
...
  environment:
    DB_CA_CERT_PATH=/usr/src/app/ca-certificate.crt
```

If you wanted to have a self-contained image, you could, again, use a `.env`  file which is copied to the image, or define these environment variables in your `Dockerfile` with the `ENV` instruction.